# Javascript select div and change href inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to modify the links in my page using JavaScript. I can select the div and the a element but cannot change the href.

Shopify is using a for loop to generate these objects and need each object to have a different link.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="tri-banner-1" class="banner-element banner-1 col-sm-4">
                <a href="collections/all"><div class="home-banner">                  
                  <img src='//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1093/4220/t/2/assets/group_top_banner01.png?17711418137279289271' alt="">
                  <div class="banner-caption">
                    <div class="display-table">
                      <div class="display-tablecell">

                      </div>
                    </div>                        
                  </div>                 
                </div></a>                                     
              </div>  



              <div id="tri-banner-2" class="banner-element banner-2 col-sm-4">
                <a href="collections/all"><div class="home-banner">                  
                  <img src='//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1093/4220/t/2/assets/group_top_banner02.png?17711418137279289271' alt="">
                  <div class="banner-caption">
                    <div class="display-table">
                      <div class="display-tablecell">

                      </div>
                    </div>                        
                  </div>                 
                </div></a>                                     
              </div>  



              <div id="tri-banner-3" class="banner-element banner-3 col-sm-4">
                <a href="collections/all"><div class="home-banner">                  
                  <img src='//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1093/4220/t/2/assets/group_top_banner03.png?17711418137279289271' alt="">
                  <div class="banner-caption">
                    <div class="display-table">
                      <div class="display-tablecell">

                      </div>
                    </div>                        
                  </div>                 
                </div></a>                                     
              </div>
```

Here is my JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(window).bind("load", function() {
      window.alert("Test");
      var banner1 = document.getElementById("tri-banner-1");
      var banner1Links = banner1.getElementsByTagName("a");
      banner1Links.href="facebook.com";
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

banner1Links gets an array value so you need to loop in that array and for every array element you pass the value

```
// instead of banner1Links.href="facebook.com";

for(var i = 0; i < banner1Links.length; i += 1){
  banner1Links[i] = 'http://example.com';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`banner1.getElementsByTagName("a");` returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) . You should either select the element using the index ; e.g.;

```
// set `href` of first `a` element in `bannerLinks`
banner1Links[0].href = "facebook.com";
```

or iterate the collection

```
for (var i = 0; i < bannerLinks.length; i++) {
  bannerLinks[i] = /* set `href` here */;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the quick response! but i dont think that will work. I need each item to have a different like and the html looks like this once the for loop generates it.

Comment: @likwidmonster _"but i dont think that will work. I need each item to have a different like and the html looks like this once the for loop generates it."_ ? What should each `href` be changed to ? Original Question only describes a single `href` substitute : "facebook.com"

Comment: @likwidmonster Given `html` at updated post you probably want to iterate elements having `id` beginning with `tri-banner` , e.g., `$("[id^=tri-banner]").each(function() {$(this).find("a").attr("href", /* set new href here */)})` instead of only `"tri-banner-1"` . This still leaves what should each `a` element `href` be changed to to make them different ?